# Why doesn't code in edit method runs again when it re-renders in case of validation failure? (Rails 3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Models in my application are **Supplier** which has_many indents , **Indent**  which has_many indent_items, **IndentItem** which has_many shipments, **Shipment** which belongs_to commercial_invoice, and **CommercialInvoice** which belongs_to supplier & has_many shipments.

Following code is there in **edit** method of CommercialInvoiceController.

```
def edit
  @commercial_invoice = CommercialInvoice.find(params[:id])

  @shipments = Shipment.includes(:indent_item => [:indent => :supplier]).where
  (:invoice_date => @commercial_invoice.start_date..@commercial_invoice.end_date).where
  (:indents => {:supplier_id => @commercial_invoice.supplier_id})
end
```

In edit page, I am using @shipments variable to render a list with check boxes. The list is rendered fine when edit page is opened. But while updating if some validation fails, the edit page is rendered again with errors but this time the @shipments variable is blank.

So I checked the console and it seems like the code isn't running again at all when the edit page is rendered again with errors.

I am not able to figure out what is happening. Please help me here.

Thanks.

Comment: The update method was already there but code wasn't in there. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit the form from the initial edit view it is submitted to the `update` action in your controller.  That needs to set the same variables used by the edit view otherwise on failure that view will not be rendered correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot smathy. I added the code in update also and now it's working fine.

Comment: Uhmmm, I don't think that there should be anything that is not passed through form required to render it?

Comment: I'm not clear on your question @MichaelSzyndel - `@commercial_invoice` and `@shipments` are both required to render his edit view, so if both of those are not also set in the `update` action then the view rendering will fail.  Neither of those are "passed through the form"

Answer (score 0):

Because it just renders a view! All objects needed for edit/form should be already set, aren't they?

Comment: I think yes, but where can I set them already then? What can be the solution? I need the list to be there even after the page is re-rendered after errors.